# Laravel 4 crashes without exception

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to integrate this https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-snappy/tree/0.1
pdf export library in my laravel 4 project. I am following the steps and when I do this:

```
After updating composer, add the ServiceProvider to the providers array in   app/config/app.php

'Barryvdh\Snappy\ServiceProvider'
```

The whole application shuts down, no exception, no error, nothing in laravel.log. Just white screen with "Ups, something went wrong". Any idea what might happened here, or at least how can I see what is the error ?

Comment: make 'debug' = true in /config/app.php file. display debug page.

Comment: what do you see in storage/logs? Is debuggin enabled ?

Comment: Have you tried to comment out 'Barryvdh\Snappy\ServiceProvider' from your service providers array and report back? Maybe there is something wrong with the package.

Comment: I changed debug' to true and it says I have permission denied for the service folder. I`m going to chmod and see if this will fix the problem.

Comment: `sudo chmod -R 755 app/storage` inside your laravel directory, you should be fine as long as permissions go...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, I`ve changed 'debug' = true in app.php and it said 'Access denied' for the services.json file. So I did chmod 755 for it and all works fine now.